# What kind of cfm can I get out of a 1/3 hp motor?

Tags: dust-collection

I want to build a Matthias Wandel style blower dust collector. However, 1/3hp is the most powerful motor I could find, from a furnace blower. How much air movement can I expect to get from this thing, or how can I calculate this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be answered as the horsepower of the motor doesn't give a direct read of its real power — two different 1/3 horsepower motors can provide very different real-world outputs because of build differences and rotor/stator quality.

Comment: The best path to the answer, by a very long shot, is to build the unit and see. Be one with the Wandel.

Answer (score 1):

My wimpy little ShopSmith dust collector is 1/2 HP and supposedly pushes a crummy 330 CFM, so I'm going to hazard a guess at 220 CFM, ballpark, using simple ratios.  Run 10 feet of flex off of that, with one or two bends in it, and your usable throughput will probably be "jack".  Simplistic, but for practical purposes, close enough.  That's a small motor, for dust collection.